# Weird behavior of qDebug() crashing the application

Tags: qt, crash, qdebug

I've been debugging a simple catalogue application and this issue is starting to get the best of me. I want to create a modal dialog, wich will recieve user input on presented data. I have a simple struct holding the catalogue item data:

```
struct ItemData {
    int nodeType;
    int nodeID;
    int nodeLevel;
    QString nodeName;
    QString nodeNote;
    QString fileName;
}
```

Then, a struct to represent the item data in the data input dialog

```
struct DialogData {
    QString name;
    QString note;
    QString file;
}
```

Now, the data input dialog is called from the main window's `editRec()` method:

```
void MainWindow::editRec()
{
    // model is defined in the main window, getSelectedRowData()
    // fills the struct with data properly
    ItemData md = model->getSelectedRowData(ui->treeView->selectionModel());

    // data, on wich the dialog will operate
    DialogData dd;

    dd.name = md.nodeName;
    dd.note = md.nodeNote;
    dd.file = md.fileName;

    // checking whether the data wich is being read from the model
    // and being passed to dialog is correct
    // qDebug '<<' operator is overloaded to handle my structs
//    qDebug << md;        // - outputs data properly, then crashes the program
//    qDebug << dd;        // - also, outputs data properly, then crashes the program

    // suspecting the error in the '<<' overload, I tried to output 
    // one field at a time and it works if I if uncomment one 
    // line at a time, but crashes the application if I try to 
    // output all fields in one go.
//  qDebug() << md.nodeType;
//  qDebug() << md.nodeID;
//  qDebug() << md.nodeLevel;
//  qDebug() << md.nodeName;
//  qDebug() << md.nodeNote;
//  qDebug() << md.fileName;

    DataDialog *dialog;

//  dialog's interface and data handling differs depending on 
//  the type of the node it will operate on
    switch (md.nodeType) {
    case NODE_ROOT: {
        dialog = new DataDialog(dlgEditRoot, false, this);
        dialog->setDialogData(dd, NODE_ROOT);
        break;
    }
    case NODE_BRANCH: {
        dialog = new DataDialog(dlgEditBranch, false, this);
        dialog->setDialogData(dd, NODE_BRANCH);
        break;
    }
    }
    dialog->initWidgets();
    if (dialog->exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {   // showing a modal dialog
        // if user changed the data, modifying the model with the new data
        if (dialog->isDataChanged) {             
            dd = dialog->getDialogData();
            switch (md.nodeType) {
            case NODE_ROOT: {
                md.nodeName = dd.name;
                md.nodeNote = dd.note;
                md.fileName = dd.file;
                model->setSelectedRowData(ui->treeView->selectionModel(), md);
                break;
            }
            case NODE_BRANCH: {
                md.nodeName = dd.name;
                md.nodeNote = dd.note;
                md.fileName = dd.file;
                model->setSelectedRowData(ui->treeView->selectionModel(), md);
                break;
            }
            }
        }
    }
    qDebug() << md;    // - both of these output data correctly without any crashes
    qDebug() << dd;    //
    delete dialog;
}
```

If I comment out the first three`qDebug()` data dumps, the whole thing works as intended.

I found only two somewhat similar issues on the StackOverflow:

- [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500991/qt-app-crashes-if-ran-without-a-qdebug-message-first) wasn't resolved
- solution from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941237/weird-qt-behavior-crashing-my-application) is not applicable in my case

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post a **complete**, single-file example. The code you show isn't sufficient to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Kuba Ober, I don't think I'll be able to cut the problematic method out and make it work without all the dependencies easily, since despite being simple the program is already rather big (over 2k lines) and uses a specific database as the data source. Can I ask you to specify which bits do you need to look at make to the diagnosis so I can add them to the post?

Comment: "I don't think I'll be able to cut the problematic method out and make it work without all the dependencies easily" Rest assured that you will be able to. Minimization is an art, there's lots to it. The crux of it is: if things don't break when you remove the code, just remove it. I can't believe that you can't remove even a single statement in your entire project without things starting to work again without a crash. So, your job is to have a single `main.cpp` where you can't remove **anything** while maintaining the crash.

Comment: The first step is to create a branch for your minimization, check out the branch, and start removing code - the more the better. Each time it compiles and still doesn't work, commit. Expect a commit pace of one per minute. I bet in an hour you'll be done, and have a nice small case that reproduces the issue. At that point you should usually be able to answer your own question, too!

Comment: 2Kuba Ober: thank you, your advice worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dig I started using [Kuba Ober](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1329652/kuba-ober)'s suggestion led me to a very deep refactoring, almost a complete rewrite, of the whole data structure I was using initially. Although I didn't find the exact cause of the crash I was getting before, I was able to fix the issue.

Some tips to someone, who might encounter a similar problem. The links I posted in the initial question were actually directly relevant to my problem. On the the first link, [Scott 'scm6079'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1895896/scott-scm6079) said:

> qDebug creates a fairly significant buffer -- which when stomped on
>   won't crash your program

I the process of rewriting I was getting exactly this kind of behavior: when my functions did not return a value, `qDebug()` was 'saving' them from a crash. After forcing all functions to return a value, the crashes stopped.

Next, if you don't subclass a `QObject` entity nor use smart pointers, pay extra attention to `new`s to match them with appropriate `delete`s. Don't create a variable in a condidional branch. If you need to create an object depending on a condidtion, refactor the differing bits out of the constructor into method you will call from conditional branch after creation. While I'm not sure whether is it good coding style or not, it certainly helped me to fix the crash.